# Out of Memory when calling Mercurial from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, mercurial

I am getting `abort: out of memory` errors when calling `hg update` or `hg pull` in a specific repository.

But I am able to perform both of those actions just fine from TortoiseHg.

Is there something that limits the amount of memory that processes started from PowerShell are allowed to use?  If so, is there a way to change that?

Or is there something else going on here?

Comment: id try the same operation prom 'pure' cmd -- not the 'powershell console', that supposing you aint trying anything posh related -- that in my humble opinion doesnt look like a posh error

Comment: It's not a posh error -- it's an hg error.  And it works fine in cmd.exe as well.